# Advantage of std::thread over pthread in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

I have seen code that uses `pthread` to write multi-threaded programs in C++ and other codes that use the `std::thread` library. What is the advantage of using the thread library instead of `pthread`?

Answer (score 16):

There are multiple adavantages. Listing those, not neccessarily in the order of importance.

1. It is cross-platform. For instance, pthreads library by default is not available on Windows. Using thread guarantees that available implementation will be used.
2. C++ threads enforce proper behaviour. For instance, an attempt to destruct a handle of not-joined, not-detached thread causes a program to abort. This is a very good thing, as it makes people aware of what they are doing.
3. C++ threads are fully incorporated into C++ as a language. No longer you have to resort to allocating your arguments in some sort of struct and passing address of this struct as a void* to your pthread routine. By using variadic templates, C++ thread library allows you to provide any number of arguments you want to your thread start routine, and does type check for you.
4. C++ threads have a nice set of surrounding classes, such as promise. Now you can actually throw exceptions from your threads without causing the whole program to crash!

Comment: @SergeyA as a newbie C++ user...should I fully embrace this, or should I go through the pain of learning this pointer(pointer){function(&pointer)} system of pthreads?  Would it be worth my time?  Or is it just a waste of time?  (In a class, limited learning time...)

Comment: @bordeo, I am not in favor of giving such broad suggestions. I believe, pointer-to-functions style is still relevant in C++, but obviously it is getting more and more out of favor and deprecated. I'd say,  learn about it, understand how it works and never use it :)